# Referência microsoft.office.interop.word não listada no Visual Studio

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2015

A referência microsoft.office.interop.word não é listada para eu adicionar ao meu projeto. O que faço para ela aparecer ?

Já habilitei a opção Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É muito provável que você tenha de importar essa Assemble, veja aqui para mais informações:

Informações sobre Assemblies
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/15s06t57(v=vs.100).aspx#pialist

Download de Assemblies Office 2010
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508

Fazendo o Download é provável que elas apareçam na lista de referências, caso contrário é só procurar no local onde ela foi instalada e adicionar.

Comment: Resolvi instalando o pacote office, que no caso, contém o assemblies.

Comment: Bom que resolveu :D

Answer (score -2):

Marque a referência Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library direto, que ele carrega todas as referências de que ela depende também.

Comment: Como ele vai marcar `Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library` se na pergunta e na imagem ficou claro que essa opção não aparece e esse fato á justamente o motivo da pergunta.